# Python sort list of dictionaries, some labels may be missing

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

How do I sort a list of dictionaries where some labels for which I want to sort may be missing?

Specifically, this list is from MPD and looks something like the following...

```
[{'title':'Bad','album': 'XSCAPE','genre':'Pop'}, {'title': 'Down to', 'album': 'Money'}]
```

I would like to sort by genre, but note the dictionary in the second item has no key for that.

Is there a built in 'Pythonic' way to do this, or will I have to build my own sort algorithm?

Comment: You are going to need to clarify, because dictionaries cannot be sorted as they lack inherent order. Do you mean you want to sort the key,value pairs of the dictionary items?

Comment: should dictionaries without a `genre` key be before or after those with a `genre` key?

Comment: juanpa: I don't want to sort the dictionary (I understand dictionaries are not sortable,) I want to sort the parent list of dictionaries. This example has a list with two items, (my list has over 5000 items) each item is a dictionary. rassar: I guess dictionaries without the desired key (genre) should be after those with keys.

Answer (score 10):

Use `sorted` function and `.get` method:

```
l = [{'title':'Bad','album': 'XSCAPE','genre':'Pop'}, {'title': 'Down to', 'album': 'Money'}]
sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.get("genre", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted`, and specify a key function:

```
output = sorted(input, key=lambda album: album['genre'] if 'genre' in album else '')
```

This puts genre-less albums first in the list (because `''` is sorted before all other strings).

Comment: I can use "else 'zzzzz'" , that should put the non existent genre after the the others.